# Fauna DB shows data from shell on web but is not working in terminal shell?

Tags: faunadb

I am learning fauna db but is not working from terminal shell.

It shows data on webshell.

```
> Paginate(Indexes())
{
    "data": [
      Index("school"),
      Index("Community")
    ]
  }
```

But does not show data on terminal shell.

```
> Paginate(Indexes())
{ data: [] }
```

Comment: Make sure you are using a key on terminal shell that points to the same database web shell is using

Comment: oh!! Thank you! I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Each secret that you use is associated with a specific database.

The web shell can access any of your databases via your username+password login. The `fauna-shell` terminal app can only use secrets, which are typically stored in `$HOME/.fauna-shell`.

If you need to, create a new key in the Dashboard for the database you wish to access via `fauna-shell` (or application code); using the key's secret gives you access to that database. Make sure that you record the new secret someplace safe, such as in `$HOME/.fauna-shell`, because it is only provided once.